# drop dataframe rows that contain entries being either -inf or NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas data frame, if there have entries being equal to  `-inf`  or `NaN`, how to remove all the related columns.

Comment: Are there non-numeric columns in the DF because `dropna` doesn't distinguish between NaN and None and NaT and any other null-like value

Comment: Columns or rows? Your title says drop rows but your description talks about dropping columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't matter that you retain other null like values (e.g. `None`, `NaT`) then replace -inf with nan and drop columns with any null values (default value of `how` arg of `dropna` is "any")

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,np.nan],
    'b': [1,-np.inf,3],
    'c': [1,2,3]
})
df = df.replace({-np.inf: np.nan}).dropna(axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
    c
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Otherwise I'd do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

TARGET_VALUES = [-np.inf, np.nan]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,np.nan],
    'b': [1,-np.inf,3],
    'c': ['a','b',None]
})
column_value_counts = df.isin(TARGET_VALUES).sum(axis=0)
df = df[column_value_counts[column_value_counts == 0].index.values].copy()
df
```

Output:

```
    c
0   a
1   b
2   None
```